# Disabling or graying out a null values rows

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have datagridview with 2 columns attached with crystal reports, in that datagridview there is 1000 rows, i populate my datagrid with this:

```
PearsonDataGrid.Rows.Add("", "")
```

so to calculate my data crystal reports and also math function dont accept null values, i have tray to put this formula to my data in column 1 and 2:

```
If IsNull ({DataTable1.XTEST}) OR {DataTable1.XTEST}="" OR Not(IsNumeric({DataTable1.XTEST}))
Then
0
Else
TONUMBER({DataTable1.XTEST})
```

and its work but crystal reports count null value and i have autre formula divided by the count so the result will be incorrect.

how to disabling or greying out null value rows in DataGridView, or how to diable rows with null value from been calculated.

Is there any easy way to disable/grey out rows with null value in DataGridView until I put numeric value.

Like spss datagrid
Example:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that fills it?

Comment: Dgv.rows.add("", "") so if it is null row will be disabled and if I put number it will be enabled

Comment: `"" != null` is `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with something like this. The code just changes the forecolor of the row headers:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable user current theme for the datagrid headers.
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        // Set the default row header style forecolor as gray.
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

        
        // I initialized the rows with null values to avoid casting to string
        // later on the CellValueChanged handler.
        
        // TEST:
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = 1.ToString();
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[1].HeaderCell.Value = 2.ToString();
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[2].HeaderCell.Value = 3.ToString();
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[3].HeaderCell.Value = 4.ToString();
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[4].HeaderCell.Value = 5.ToString();
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, null);
        //dataGridView1.Rows[5].HeaderCell.Value = 6.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cell value changed event handler.
    /// </summary>
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Avoid to process less than zero indexed rows.
        if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;
        // Get the current row.
        var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        bool isRowEmpty = true;
        // Iterate on every cell to check if every cell has a null value.
        if (currentRow.Cells.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in currentRow.Cells)
            {
                if (!(cell.Value is null))
                {
                    isRowEmpty = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isRowEmpty)
        {
            // Every row cell is empty, gray out the header.
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            // Some cell has a value, set the row header forecolor to black.
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        } 
    }
```

This is the resulting effect:

[image]

Comment: thank you with your answer you solved two problem at ones